# How to override a configuration-level property in a properties file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

In our project files we have stuff like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>8.1</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I want to use a standard properties file to override the Platform Toolset and Windows SDK across any project which uses it. I tried this in a .props file:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This does update the Windows SDK version, but not the platform toolset:
[image]

I am assuming it's because in the project file `v141` is specified on a per-configuration basis, but I really don't want to add every possible configuration to the .props file as we have quite a lot... is it possible to put something in the .props file *once* which will override all the configurations?

Comment: According to the documentation, a .props file cannot override project settings. If you need to override properties, do it in a .targets file"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022#choose-between-adding-properties-to-a-props-or-targets-file

Answer (score 3):

It seems, for C++, there are some differences.

Refer to this document: [Customize C++ builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#customize-c-builds), and this similar thread: [Overridden settings inside Directory.Build.props or Directory.Build.targets are not shown in project properties](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/overridden-settings-inside-directorybuildprops-or/983193).

**The document mentioned:**

“For C++ projects, the previously mentioned custom .targets and .props files cannot be used in the same way to override default settings. Directory.Build.props is imported by Microsft.Common.props, which is imported in `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props` while most of the defaults are defined in Microsoft.Cpp.props and …”

“But, you can use the following properties to specify .props file(s) to be automatically imported before/after Microsoft.Cpp.* files:
`ForceImportAfterCppDefaultProps`
`ForceImportBeforeCppProps`
`ForceImportAfterCppProps`
…
”
“To customize the default values of properties for all C++ builds, create another .props file (say, MyProps.props), and define the `ForceImportAfterCppProps` property in Directory.Build.props pointing to it”

“MyProps.props will be automatically imported at the very end of Microsoft.Cpp.props.”

**I think**

This explains why you failed to use `<PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>` to override the Platform Toolset value. You can have a try create a new .props file and like the document mentioned, define `ForceImportAfterCppProps`/`ForceImportBeforeCppProps` property in Directory.Build.props file to point to it (new .props file), and add the msbuild code in the new .props file to override the Platform Toolset value.

**What I tested**

Generate two `.props` file, one called `Directory.Build.props`, and the other called `MyProps.props`.

Just did some simple tests, add related codes in `Directory.Build.props` file, as you know:

```xml
    <Project>
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
      <ForceImportBeforeCppProps>$(MsbuildThisFileDirectory)\MyProps.props</ForceImportBeforeCppProps>
      <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

And add these codes in `MyProps.props` file:

```xml
    <Project>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
        <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
      </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
        <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
      </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
        <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
      </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
        <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

And then save and build the project.

**The results**

I tested to change v142 to v141, v140, and change 10.0.18362.0 to 10.0.19042.0, and yes, the Windows SDK version changed as expected, but for platform toolset, it seems from the project property option, the platform toolset option doesn’t change, but from Solution Explorer, you may see that the project name has changed like this `XXXXXXX (Visual Studio 2017)` (if you use v 141), and  `XXXXXXX (Visual Studio 2015)` (if you use v140), and VS may not refresh as quick as possible, you can try to close solution and open the solution again in VS.

Comment: +1, but the fact that in your own property sheet (as opposed to the project file) you keep using to set the `Condition` attribute and then repeat the same thing four times, is cargo-cult-y. Simply lose the `Condition` and three of the `PropertyGroup` elements and you're done. Even better: if you have a non-standard project also targeting, say, ARM64, the solution without the condition will keep working. Only use conditions when you actually want to distinguish.